# generators and relations of symmetric group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $S_{n}$ be symmetric group. Then it is given by generators $\tau_{i}$ where $i=1,2,\ldots,n-1$ and relations
$${\tau_{i}}^2$$
$$\tau_{i}\tau_{j}=\tau_{j}\tau_{i}\text{ for }i\neq j\pm1$$ 
$$\tau_{i}\tau_{i+1}\tau_{i}=\tau_{i+1}\tau_{i}\tau_{i+1}$$
I will be pleased if someone can present me detailed proof of this fact.

Comment: I would like to know if there is a conceptually different (yet reasonable) proof besides the reflection group approach. So, I am offering a bounty on this question.

Comment: Please note that I think that the current answer *does* contain enough detail to be an answer to the original question, but I didn't want to start a new question with basically the same content, and this was the closest one in the choices for bounty messages.

Comment: In the book "Braid groups" by Kassel and Turaev, there is an elementary proof in chapter 4.1. http://books.google.de/books?id=y6Cox3XjdroC&pg=PA151&lpg=PA151&dq=generators+and+relations+of+the+symmetric+group&source=bl&ots=eB8Uezuoft&sig=DJUTs9DVO0ikhRXwu_I5iy8e1ck&hl=en&sa=X&ei=L6i3UOfqKIPJtAaD-4C4CA&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=generators%20and%20relations%20of%20the%20symmetric%20group&f=false

Comment: If you don’t want the reflection group aspect, you can do it completely combinatiorally, using parabolic subgroups in Coxeter groups. It is however a “reflection group approach in disguise”, so I don’t know if this is what you’re looking for.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Basically, I am looking for an answer that can easily be given to students who have just learned the basics about groups (such an answer is now here), and I am also very interested in other elegant answers of any theoretical level that use some neat trick I am unaware of. So, I am not really looking for a way to "disguise" the advanced aspect.

Comment: @Phira : I see. I think you'll agree YACP's solution below is the perfect solution, then.

Answer (score 8):

We shall refer to the above relations as the *Moore relations*.

Set $\tau_i=(i\ i+1)\in S_n$ for $i=1,\dots,n-1$. It's easily seen that these transpositions satisfy the Moore relations.

> **Theorem.** Let $G$ be a group defined by generators $\tau_1, \tau_2, \ldots, \tau_{n-1}$ and the Moore relations. Then $G\simeq S_n$.

*Proof.*

> It's well known that $S_n$ is a homomorphic image of $G$. If we show that $|G|\leq |S_n|$, then we are done.

Induction on $n$. There is nothing to prove for $n=1$. Suppose $n>1$.

> By the induction hypothesis, the subgroup $H=\langle\tau_2,\dots,\tau_{n-1}\rangle$ of $G$ satisfies $\left|H\right| \leq \left|S_{n-1}\right|$ (since $H$ is a homomorphic image of the group with generators $\tau_2,\ldots,\tau_{n-1}$ and the Moore relations without the ones that involve $\tau_1$), and therefore it is enough to prove that $[G:H]\le n$.

Let $H_1=H, H_2=H_1\tau_1,\dots, H_n=H_{n-1}\tau_{n-1}$. We have $H_{i+1}\tau_i=H_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n-1$. Furthermore, if $i\neq j,j+1$, then $H_i\tau_j=H_i$. In order to show this let's set $\sigma_i=\tau_1\cdots\tau_{i-1}$ and note that $H_i=H\sigma_i$.

If $j\ge i+1$, then $\tau_j$ commutes with $\sigma_i$ and we get 
$$H_i\tau_j=H\sigma_i\tau_j=H\tau_j\sigma_i=H\sigma_i=H_i.$$ 
(We have used $H\tau_j=H$ which is true because $\tau_j\in H$).

If $1\le j<i-1$, then $\sigma_i=\sigma_j\tau_j\tau_{j+1}\sigma$, where $\sigma$ commutes with $\tau_j$. Thus $$H_i\tau_j=H\sigma_j\tau_j\tau_{j+1}\sigma\tau_j=H\sigma_j(\tau_j\tau_{j+1}\tau_j)\sigma=H\sigma_j(\tau_{j+1}\tau_j\tau_{j+1})\sigma=H\tau_{j+1}\sigma_j\tau_{j}\tau_{j+1}\sigma=H\sigma_j\tau_j\tau_{j+1}\sigma=H\sigma_i=H_i.$$ 
(We have used $H\tau_{j+1}=H$ which is true because $\tau_{j+1}\in H$).

Since $G=\langle\tau_1,\dots,\tau_n\rangle$, the relations above show that any right coset in $G$ modulo $H$ coincides with one of the $H_i$, and this is enough to conclude that $[G:H]\le n$.

**Remark.** I know this proof since I was a student, but I don't remember the source.

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind to emphasize the "idea" lines with ">" (first two sentences and the "By the induction hypothesis" sentence)? I will wait out the bounty to see if another proof comes along, but don't worry, if someone else posts another nifty different proof, I will just put on a second bounty to reward everyone.

Comment: That's not what I meant, so I just did it myself, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question, it is to show that the symmetric group $S_n$ is exactly the universal group on those generators with those relations. That is, that it is the quotient of the free group on $n$ generators by the smallest normal subgroup containing the relators.

The potential issue would be that $S_n$ might be a proper quotient of the actual universal group with those relations.

One device to understand $S_n$ is as a *Coxeter* group: the actual universal group $W$ with generators $s_j$ and relations as in the question is by definition a Coxeter group, and the _reflection_representation_ $W\rightarrow O(V)$ to the orthogonal group of the corresponding invariant quadratic form (from the Coxeter data) is proven *injective* by consideration of the *length* function on the group. It is not entirely trivial to prove this (see the Corollary on p. 7 of http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/buildings/book.pdf, for example).

To see that $S_n$ is isomorphic to $W$, rather than to a proper quotient, we need a natural representation of $S_n$ on an $(n-1)$-dimensional vector space $V$ preserving a quadratic form isomorphic to the Coxeter form. Indeed, and unsurprisingly, the restriction of the Killing form to the diagonal matrices in the Lie algebra $sl(n)$ of $SL(n)$ is preserved by the conjugation (Adjoint) action of $n$-by-$n$ permutation matrices, and is a scalar multiple of the Coxeter quadratic form.

This may seem circuitous or long-winded, but it is fairly conceptual, and applies to concrete realizations of the (spherical) Weyl groups of the other classical groups, as well.