# Word processing of Coxeter group $E_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras

Exercise 5.4.11 of Hartshorne book "Algebraic geometry" gives a definition of the relationship between Weyl groups, as follows:
Given any diagram consisting of points and line segments joining some of them, we define an abstract group, given by generators and relations, as follows: each point represents a generator $x_i$. The relations are $x_i^2=1$ for each $i$, $(x_ix_j)^2=1$ if $i$ and $j$  are not joined by a line segment, and $(x_ix_j)^3=1$ if $i$ and $j$ are joined by a line segment.

The Weyl group $E_6=\langle x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,y\rangle$ is defined using the following diagram: $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ are joined by a line segment $(1\leq i\leq 4)$, and there is an additional node $y$ which is only joined by a line segment to $x_3$.

The last question of this exercise is to calculate the order of $E_6$ and finally prove that it is isomorphic to the automorphism group of 27 lines on a cubic surface (the mapping has been constructed in the second question). I can prove isomorphism, but Hartshorne seems to mean to use elementary group theory to calculate the number of elements(which means relying only on the above definition). I consulted some literature on Lie algebra, and the methods they used are not elementary. And I know the number of elements of $E_6$ is $51840$.

I discussed this problem with my classmates and some people who are willing to help me in mathematics. One person said that this is a word processing of the Coxeter group, and no papers in this field have been searched. So how to calculate and whether my understanding is wrong. Does Hartshorne mean this?

Comment: I doubt that's what Hartshorne had in mind. The phrase "Word processing" in connection with group theory only came about after the 1992 publication of the book [Word Processing in Groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_Processing_in_Groups), well after the 1977 publication of Hartshorne's book. I also doubt that Hartshorne intended one to use *only* elementary group theory. The computation of 51840 elements depends, I believe, on the knowledge of [isomorphs of $E_6$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E6_(mathematics)#Weyl_group). But perhaps an expert on Weyl groups can confirm this.

Comment: Hartshorne asked to "estimate" the order of $E_6$, not calculate. So I imagine it's really about putting some bounds on the order of $E_6$, so that given there is a surjective homomorphism $E_6 \to G$, whose order you already know, you can conclude that the two groups must be isomorphic.

Comment: My initial practice was to verify that $G$ met the definition relations of $E_6$, so these relations defined a subgroup of $G$. Then we embed $E_6$ into $G$, and the embedding is injection, and the surjection of the second question is isomorphism. Is that right? Or how to estimate the order of $E_6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similarly to [this proof of part (a)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200840/generators-and-relations-of-symmetric-group), one can calculate right coset representatives. The trick is doing it twice: once for the inclusion $H=\langle x_1,x_2,x_3,y\rangle \subset \langle x_1,x_2,x_3,y,x_4 \rangle = F$ and once for $F=\langle x_1,x_2,x_3,y,x_4 \rangle\subset \langle x_1,x_2,x_3,y,x_4,x_5 \rangle= E_6$. As $\langle x_1,x_2,x_3,y \rangle \cong S_5$ from part (a), the first group is of order 120, so if we can show that there are at most 16 right coset representatives of $H$ in $F$ and at most 27 right coset representatives of $F$ in $E_6$, then we can bound from above the order of the group given by generators and relations by $120\cdot 16\cdot 27 = 51840$.

Here is a graph of the right coset representatives for the first inclusion, where each right coset is a node, and a labeled edge between two nodes corresponds to right multiplication by the labeled element taking you between the two nodes. If a node corresponding to the right coset $Hz$ has no edge labeled by $x_i$ or $y$, then $Hzx_i=Hz$ or $Hzy=Hz$, respectively. (This is actually the meat of the claim: proving this shows that there are *at most* this many right coset representatives. I will skip recording this in the post, it is somewhat tedious.)

[image: First graph of right coset representatives]

Here is the same graph with the same rules for the right coset representatives of the second inclusion ([quiver link](https://q.uiver.app/#q=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)):

[image: Second graph of right coset representatives]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Does this method also compute the order of $E_7=\langle x_1,x_2,x_3,y,x_4,x_5,x_6\rangle$ and $E_8=\langle x_1,x_2,x_3,y,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7\rangle$? We know that $|E_7/E_6|=56$ and $|E_8/E_7|=240$, but right cosets are tricky to calculate.

Comment: There's no reason why it wouldn't work, but it definitely would take some time and care. Depending on your aims, it might be worth investing some time in learning a bit more theory to calculate the size of those groups.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure I use to count the order of a Weyl group is to use orbit-stabilizer. We know that the root system has $72$ roots, all the same length, so they form a single orbit of the Weyl group. The highest root is the only one in the closure of the dominant Weyl chamber, and it is also the fundamental dominant weight related to the simple root that "sticks out" in the Dynkin diagram. Hence the stabilizer that root is a Coxeter group of type $A_5$. That is, isomorphic to $S_6$.

Therefore the order of this Weyl group is
$$|\Phi|\cdot |S_6|=72\cdot720=51840.$$